# Click LinkedIn share button using Robot framework selenium library

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am  a newbie in using robot framework.I would like to click linkedin share button using selenium library. From my understanding linkedin share button is of type submit and value Share. can someone suggest how to use click element or click button for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to help you get started:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Click share
    Open Browser
    ...  url=https://put-your-link-here
    ...  browser=googlechrome
    Click Button  Share
```

Just put the right URL there, choose the browser you want to use, and check the name of the button. You can give this a go saving it to a file `test.robot`, for example, and run it with:

`pybot test.robot`

From there, the [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html) is your best friend.

Comment: Click Button Share doesn't work. since it is of input type= submit. Below is the html code. <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Share">

Comment: Button with locator 'Share' not found error when i use.  Click Button  Share

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. Before clicking an element should make sure that the element is visible. So below is the code 
Wait Until Element is Visible    css=input[value="Share"]
Click Element    css=input[value="Share"]